# What is the easiest way to determine if a character is in Unicode range, in Rust?

Tags: unicode-string, rust

I'm looking for easiest way to determine if a character in Rust is between two Unicode values.

For example, I want to know if a character `s` is between `[#x1-#x8]` or `[#x10FFFE-#x10FFFF]`. Is there a function that does this already?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way for me to match a character was this

```
fn match_char(data: &char) -> bool {
    match *data {
        '\x01'...'\x08' |
        '\u{10FFFE}'...'\u{10FFFF}' => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}
```

Pattern matching a character was the easiest route for me, compared to a bunch of `if` statements. It might not be the most performant solution, but it served me very well.

Comment: Performance should be the same with this as with my answer. Personally, I prefer my technique to this one in this case (if there were a non-boolean output or more possibilities I would use match), but either will do as well.

Comment: It's readability for me. I have a lot of those conditions (opinions differ - shocking), I'd either go the route of match patterns for readability or go for `char-'\x01'<=7` for speed see [aosabook-xml at speed of light](http://aosabook.org/en/posa/parsing-xml-at-the-speed-of-light.html)

Comment: @DanielFath Thanks for the awesome snippet! As of 2021, the `...` range patterns are deprecated, consider using `..=` for an inclusive range (E0783).

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way, assuming that they are not Unicode categories (in which case you should be using `std::unicode`) is to use the regular comparison operators:

```
(s >= '\x01' && s <= '\x08') || s == '\U0010FFFE' || s == '\U0010FFFF'
```

(In case you weren't aware of the literal forms of these things, one gets 8-bit hexadecimal literals `\xXX`, 16-bit hexadecimal literals `\uXXXX`, and 32-bit hexadecimal literals `\UXXXXXXXX`. Matter of fact, casts would work fine too, e.g. `0x10FFFE as char`, and would be just as efficient; just less easily readable.)

Comment: Note that the integer-to-char casts are unsafe and may disappear: e.g. `0xFFFF_FFFF as char` is allowed, even though it's not a valid codepoint. (Also `std::unicode` is currently private; (most of) its functionality is accessed via `std::char` and `std:::str`.)